# How to reduce dc 5 volt to below 1.5v by add extra load

Tags: circuit-design, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter, electronic-load

I have an USB charger with 5V DC output.

I want to use this charger to power a 1.2V DC motor.

I think about adding an extra load, like a DC bulb, to this circuit, maybe it could reduce the voltage to my requirements.

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome. You have no voltage regulation, so the voltage will change with the motor load.

Comment: Consider using a low cost adjustable voltage regulator such as a LM317.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm afraid it's not a free design house or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: @TonyM Don't afraid . I am not electrical engineer.   i run directly by 5v dc input to 1.2v dc motor more heat comes. Thats why i ask here.    Also i am not expert in circuit design.   #Marcus mullar My idea slightly differ so not exactly match the old post. #sparky256 Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnKF4b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The wiring circuit.*

The problem is that motors don't behave like resistors. The more load you put on the motor the lower its resistance will become and the more current it will try to draw. If you got the right lamp it could protect the motor enough but when the motor is lightly loaded the voltage would rise and the motor may run much more quickly than designed. It certainly won't run at constant speed if the load changes.

A simple fix would be to use diodes which drop about 0.7 V across them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4LBDX.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simple solution to drop about 3.5 V from the PSU.*

This will work reasonably well although you'll be wasting 70% of the power in the diodes and only using 30% in the motor. You might be able to find these in some junk if you don't have any handy.